# Axios response in route before each

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new to Vue so don't know how I achieve the following:

I want an Axios response so I can match the response token with a locally stored token because I found that if I modify the token value in local store, the user can still navigate from any secure route.

Is there any other method to secure this?

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){

    const authUser = localStorage.getItem('authUser')
    console.log(authUser);
    var session='here i want axios response value'

    if (!authUser===session){
      console.log('here log');
      next({ path: '/', })
    } else {
      console.log('else redirect');
      next()
    }
  } else {
    console.log('bhar else redirect');
    next()  
  } 
});
```

Here is my login.vue success loginpost method:

```
    loginPost(){
           var _this = this
           var vm = this.hasErrors
           var _vm = this.errorMessage
           var log = {
                      companyname: this.loginData.companyname,
                      username: this.loginData.both,
                      password: this.loginData.password,
                    }

            this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/login', log)
            .then(function (response) {
           if(response.status=== 200){
          this.$store.commit('authUser', response.data.id)
            localStorage.setItem('authUser', response.data.id)
            _this.$router.push('/authuser');
           }else{
            console.log('unknow');
           }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                var errors = error.response;
                if(errors.statusText === 'Unprocessable Entity'){
                    if(errors.data){
                        if(error.response.data.error.details.messages.username){
                           vm.both = true
                           _vm.both = error.response.data.error.details.messages.username[0]
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should use vuex with plugin `createPersistedState` ... local storage is not the way to do it. Plus, how are you navigating to the pages? you must have finished a req/response cycle to navigate to another page so ... capturing axios response when the page has decided to navigate is kinda bad imho

Comment: @samayo can you give me link or any method or any example

Comment: you have to install the vue-cli and install vue, add vuex and `createPersistedState` plugin.

Comment: @samayo done with installation now

Comment: make sure to set up your vuex with persistance and let me know

Comment: @samayo done now how i can complete my  requirement import step also done

Comment: Check this file how they are doing it. https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue#L49-L75 once you hit the login api and get the token then store that token inside your vuex store, after than you can check inside your router if the token exists by checking the store

Comment: @samayo updated my question is this correct way to store or i need something more

Comment: the second code looks okay. You don't need to store in localstorage if you are commiting/storing it in vuex. Check your vue-devtools to see if vuex has stored your state, after that just call store inside your router to check if there is a token stored in it. You need these files https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/tree/master/src/store inside your src and configure this https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/store/state.js as per your need. You can put only one object  ex: `export default {token: ''}` if you want.

Comment: change the https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/store/mutations.js files also.

Comment: to something like `export default {
   LOGIN_USER (state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }`
}

Comment: after that, change the commit (in your second code) to this: `this.$store.commit('LOGIN_USER', response.data.id)`

Comment: @samayo in mutation file  LOGIN_USER (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  }, what is this user

Comment: it's the user info that you pass down to vuex for storage. You can create as many state (one being `user`) as you need to store information based on categories. I have for ex: userInfo, orgInfo, preferences .... on my app